# Install Tensorly library with apt on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pip, apt, tensorly

I am running Ubuntu 23.04 with Python 3.11.4

I would like to install the Tensorly library into my Python environment.
The Tensorly instructions say to use pip (or Conda).  However, when I do so, I see this message:

```
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
```

And if I try to install it via apt:

```
sudo apt install python3-tensorly
```

I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3-tensorly
```

How do I proceed to get this installed?

Comment: "*I would like to install the Tensorly library into my Python environment.*" A Python virtual environment, I hope. Using `pip` or `conda` means using Python virtual environments. So create and **activate** a Python virtual environment, then install packages.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest if you're not familiar with the Python ecosystem is probably to just install the [Anaconda distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/download) (typically locally) and do everything there rather than use the system-wide python version.

As mentioned in the comment it is a good practice to work in a virtual environment.